# Joda-time to date with timezone in java

Tags: java, date, timezone, jodatime, dst

Having a Date, I can build a DateTime of joda:

```
  DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( date, timeZone_MADRID )
```

When I try to retrieve the date using:

```
dateTimeUtc.toDate()
```

It loses the timezone value because java.util.Date doesn't know TimeZones. But I need a process to modify the Date value depending of TimeZone.

That's it: if timezone of Madrid is +2 and my object Date has a value of 1/1/2000 12:00, after ths "process" value of Date would be 1/1/2000 14:00

Which is the proper way to get it?

Comment: It's really unclear what you mean, but a `Date` should *not* be mangled to manually include an offset. It *always* represented an instant in time. Just creating a `DateTime` with a `Date` and then getting a `Date` back from it should give you a `Date` equal to the first one. If you're expecting anything else, you've misunderstood `Date`.

Comment: Sorry if I have not explained clearly. In fact, I have a really big project which uses a lot of new Date(). And this project must be internationalized, so in order to do this, I must create an "interceptor" which can get all new Dates() to change timezones before store to BD and after retrieve of BD. So is not a question about change uses of Date to JodaTime. I hope it helps.

Comment: There's no such concept as "change time zone" for `java.util.Date`. Now is now, and would be represented by the same `Date` object regardless of time zone. It sounds like you're trying to take a short cut to avoid doing things properly. Don't. Bite the bullet and fix your systems appropriately. **Anything else will cause issues in the long term, and will be really hard to fix.**

Comment: @ilopezluna You should listen to Jon Skeet. Mangling the use of java.util.Date will bring you nothing but confusion, pain, and tears. In general, avoid j.u.Date whenever possible. Use Joda-Time objects preferably (or java.time). Where you cannot, then serialize to s String representation in [ISO 8601] format. Joda-Time produces such strings by default.

Comment: Citation: "to modify the Date value depending of TimeZone". No you cannot modify the fixed `Date`-reference to UTC. But you can keep an extra timezone object and then use that together with `Date`-object in your process (but as Jon Skeet correctly said: don't mangle the `Date`-object with any kind of offset or zone). And: "Date has a value of 1/1/2000 12:00", no, `Date` has not this value, only a long-primitive representing the elapsed millisecs since UNIX epoch in UTC zone.

Comment: Ok, thanks for your comments. I will think for another way to solve it. I'm little scared about modify all code of project where Date is been used, so I will come back with new questions, sure :P

Answer (score 1):

Try like this

```
      DateTime dateTimeUtc = new DateTime( new Date(), DateTimeZone.forID("Etc/GMT+11"));
      System.out.println(dateTimeUtc);
      System.out.println(dateTimeUtc.toDate());
```

output:
2014-07-01T05:45:51.791-11:00
Tue Jul 01 22:15:51 IST 2014

You can get available time zone ids from `TimeZone.getAvailableIDs();`